# Understanding a proof that, for every integer $n$, $6|n$ iff $2|n$ and $3|n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm learning how to write proofs with *How To Prove It* by Daniel J. Valleman. Theorem 3.4.6. says as follows:

> For every integer $n$, $6|n$ iff $2|n$ and $3|n$.

Here's a proof by the author:

> *Proof.* Let $n$ be an arbitrary integer.
>
> - ($\rightarrow$). Suppose $6 | n$. Then we can choose an integer $k$ such that $6k = n$. Therefore $n = 6k = 2(3k)$, so $2 | n$, and similarly $n = 6k = 3(2k)$, so $3 | n$.
> - ($\leftarrow$). Suppose $2 | n$ and $3 | n$. Then we can choose integers j and k such that $n=2j$ and $n=3k$. Therefore $6(j−k)=6j−6k=3(2j)−2(3k)=3n−2n=n$, so $6 | n$.

**My question is**:

> How did he find $(j-k)$?

This is what I know: the goal of the proof (the second part) is $6 | n$, which means $\exists m\in\mathbb{Z}(6m = n)$, so all I have to do is find $m$, which is $(j-k)$. I don't know how the author found it.

I suspect that's a very fundamental high school thing, so I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question, but I've always been bad at math and I started working with proofs recently because I want to get good at math. Is it easy to see without much effort that $(j-k)$ works? Do I simply need more practice with these proofs and eventually I'll see things like these more easily? This is the reasoning the author gives about using $6(j-k)$:

*For the right-to-left direction we assume $2|n$ and $3|n$ and prove $6|n$. Once again, the introduction of j and k is justified by existential instantiation. **No explanation is given for why we should compute 6( j − k)**, but a proof need not provide such explanations. The reason for the calculation should become clear when, surprisingly, it turns out that 6( j − k) = n. Such surprises provide part of the pleasure of working with proofs. As in the first half of the proof, since j − k is an integer, this shows that 6 | n.*

Thanks in advance and sorry for not being more succinct. This is the best I could do.

Comment: By "find", do you mean "compute" or "realized they should compute"? The proof as stated already addresses the former. For the latter, they probably noted $n/2-n/3=n/6$.

Comment: As the author says, writing a proof is not about explaining the process of finding it. Finding the right "trick" may be coming from many trials and errors. Here, writing $n = 3n - 2n$ may be natural since the $3n$ includes a $2$ (since $2\mid n$) and the $2n$ includes a $3$ (since $3 \mid n$), so it is reasonable to toy with these expressions. They may not have worked, and are of the same kind as using $+1-1$ expressions to transform suitable expressions so that they simplify nicely. But we do these trials keeping in mind what we want to happen at the end (here, 6 factoring out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the idea is the following, we know that $n=2j$ and $n=3k$, then we can multiple by $3$ and $2$ to appear the number $6$. Following that we obtain

$3n=6j$ and $2n=6k$, and so $n= 3n-2n=6j-6k=6(j-k)$.